# How to use zend i18n module in mix php/other framework?

Tags: php, zend-framework2, zend-translate

I want to use ZF2 i18n module in my custom php project.
My composer.json file as bellow

```
{
    "require": {
        "zendframework/zend-i18n": "2.3.*@dev"
    }
}
```

My index.php file is

```
include_once './vendor/autoload.php';

use Zend\I18n\Translator\Translator;

$translator = new Translator();
$translator->setLocale('fr_FR');
echo $translator->translate('All rights reserved.');
```

My question how to set base dir for language where I store en_US.po, fr_FR.po file for translation and when I set $translator->setLocale('fr_FR'); then french version of 'All rights reserved.' text show.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a pattern to the translator in order to get it working (you've got two languages supported). Using a pattern allows you to add more locales without changing your code. Use the `addTranslationPattern` function. The function definition is:

```
//$type -> format loader
//$baseDir -> the dir where you place your locale files
//$pattern -> sprintf expression (the locale is parsed through it)
//$textDomain -> category specified for the file. By default is 'default'
public function addTranslationFilePattern($type, $baseDir, $pattern, $textDomain = 'default')
```

Use it like:

```
$translator = new Translator();
$translator->addTranslationFilePattern('gettext', '<your_base_dir>', '%s.mo');
```

Check the [reference](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.3/en/modules/zend.i18n.translating.html) for more information.

Comment: Hi @lluisaznar thanks for reply, I got this following error .
 Fatal error: Class 'Zend\ServiceManager\AbstractPluginManager' not found in D:\xampp\htdocs\zf2\translate\vendor\zendframework\zend-i18n\Zend\I18n\Translator\LoaderPluginManager.php on line 56

Comment: It seems that there are dependencies. The `LoaderPluginManager` extends the class `Zend\ServiceManager\AbstractPluginManager`. The I18n **composer.json** defines `zendframework/zend-servicemanager` as a requirement. Have you checked if you've got it installed in your zf2 library folder?